# Sequence does not come out right

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows,decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]

\node (A) at (1,0) {$0$};
\node (B) at (2,0) {$H^1(G/H,M^H$};
\node (C) at (3,0) {$H^1(G,M)$};
\node (D) at (4,0) {$H^1(H,M)$};
\path[->,font=\scriptsize,>=angle 90]
(A) edge node[above]{} (B)
(B) edge node[above]{$\textnormal{Inf}$} (C)
(C) edge node[above]{$\textnormal{Res}$} (D);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

I'm writing a LaTeX document with this code and while the diagram has appeared in the right order, they are squeezed together because of the length of the elements in the sequence. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 7):

You want to use `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Inf}{Inf}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Res}{Res}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
0 \arrow{r} &
H^1(G/H,M^H) \arrow{r}{\Inf} &
H^1(G,M) \arrow{r}{\Res} &
H^1(H,M)
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not a specialist in group cohomology, but I've used several diagrams and exact sequences. ;-)

Comment: I got this error when I typed the code into my latex document in SAGE:

<inserted text> 
                \cr 
l.231 
      
! Misplaced \cr.
<inserted text> \cr 

Do you know what's wrong?

Comment: @HaikalYeo Sorry, but I don't know about SAGE. Are you sure you have an up-to-date TeX distribution?

Comment: Have a look at the [Sage tutorial](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/tutorial/latex.html) where there are instructions about how to include latex packages.